# Finding whether a word exist in a string in python

Tags: python

Here is the piece of code where i want help.

```
listword=["os","slow"]
sentence="photos"
if any(word in sentence for word in listword):
    print "yes"
```

It prints yes as os is present in photos.
  But I want to know whether there is **os as a "word" is present** in the string instead of os present **as part of the word**.Is there any way without converting **sentence into list of words**.Basically i dont want the program to print yes.It has to print yes only if string contains os **word**.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean by "not splitting it into a list of words" and why

Comment: It means that s/he already knows about `sentence.split()`, which is another way to solve the problem.

Comment: @alexis That's possible but this is a really weird request...

Comment: @vindhya, why wouldn't you want to `split()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to use regular expressions, and add `\b` word boundary anchors around each word when matching:

```
import re

if any(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(word)), sentence) for word in listword):
    print 'yes'
```

The `\b` boundary anchor matches at string start and end points, and anywhere there is a transition between word and non-word characters (so between a space and a letter or digit, or between punctuation and a letter or digit).

The [`re.escape()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) ensures that all regular expression metacharacters are escaped and we match on the literal contents of `word` and not accidentally interpret anything in there as an expression.

Demo:

```
>>> listword = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> sentence = 'The quick fox jumped over the barred door'
>>> if any(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(word)), sentence) for word in listword):
...     print 'yes'
... 
>>> sentence = 'The tradition to use fake names like foo, bar or baz originated at MIT'
>>> if any(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(word)), sentence) for word in listword):
...     print 'yes'
... 
yes
```

By using a regular expression, you now can match case-insensitively as well:

```
if any(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(word)), sentence, re.I) for word in listword):
    print 'yes'
```

In this demo both `the` and `mit` qualify even though the case in the sentence differs:

```
>>> listword = ['the', 'mit']
>>> if any(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(word)), sentence, re.I) for word in listword):
...     print 'yes'
... 
yes
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..it worked..although i dont know what re.escape does i will find it out from documentation..

Comment: @vindhya: It escapes any regular expression meta characters in `word` to make sure you match the literal word, not any accidental regular expression the word may contain.

Answer (score 1):

As people have pointed out, you can use regular expressions to split your string into a list words.  This is known as tokenization.

If regular expressions aren't working well enough for you, then I suggest having a look at [NTLK](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html) -- a Python natural language processing library.  It contains a wide range of tokenizers that will split your string based on whitespace, punctuation, and other features that may be too tricky to capture with a regex.

Example:

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, wordpunct_tokenize, sent_tokenize
>>> s = '''Good muffins cost $3.88\nin New York.  Please buy me
... two of them.\n\nThanks.'''
>>> wordpunct_tokenize(s)
['Good', 'muffins', 'cost', '$', '3', '.', '88', 'in', 'New', 'York', '.',
'Please', 'buy', 'me', 'two', 'of', 'them', '.', 'Thanks', '.']
>>> "buy" in wordpunct_tokenize(s)
True
```

Comment: Although this is a good solution, your example is simply splitting into words which OP does not want if you look at the question

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, and will not work if `sentence` string contains commas, but still

```
if any (" {0} ".format a in sentence for a in listword):
```

Comment: You can prepend space to sentence, it is still better than regexps.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> sentence="photos"
>>> listword=["os","slow"]
>>> pat = r'|'.join(r'\b{0}\b'.format(re.escape(x)) for x in listword)
>>> bool(re.search(pat, sentence))
False
>>> listword=["os","slow", "photos"]
>>> pat = r'|'.join(r'\b{0}\b'.format(re.escape(x)) for x in listword)
>>> bool(re.search(pat, sentence))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

While I especially like the tokenizer and the regular expression solutions, I do believe they are kind of overkill for this kind of situation, which can be very effectively solved just by using the [str.find() method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find).

```
listword = ['os', 'slow']
sentence = 'photos'
for word in listword:
    if sentence.find(word) != -1:
       print 'yes'
```

Although this might not be the most elegant solution, it still is (in my opinion) the most suitable solution for people that just started out fiddling with the language.